# How to add a row dynamically in a tableLayout in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, row, addition, tablelayout

I have a function who gets a list of products from a webpage, and I want to add a row in a tableLayout for each element of the list.

```
public void getProductsOfCategory() throws IOException{
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                //background code...
                try {
                    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                    String categoryName = extras.getString("categoryName");

                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://romal.hopto.org/foodadvisor/users/getProductsOfCategory.json?category="+categoryName);
                    HttpResponse httpresp = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    httpresp.getEntity().writeTo(baos);
                    final String content = new String(baos.toByteArray());
                    CategoryActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            //foreground code (UI)
                            //update user interface, for example, showing messages
                            try {
                                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(content);
                                JSONArray productsList = jObject.getJSONArray("response");
                                for(int i=0; i<productsList.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject product = productsList.getJSONObject(i);
                                    JSONObject productData = product.getJSONObject("Product");
                                    String productDescription = productData.getString("description");
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }   
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

In my layout xml file I have defined the table layout like this:

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableOfProducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:paddingRight="14dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </TableLayout>
```

I imagine I have to add some extra code in the for loop, adding a new row and a new textview for each element, and setting the content of the text view with the string that has the description of the product.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this out, this is the general way of creating table rows dynamically. Modify it accordingly

**XML file**

```
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/main_table"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">
</TableLayout>
```

**JAVA PART**

```
TableLayout t1;

TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
```

**Create table row header to hold the column headings**

```
TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
tr_head.setId(10);
tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);        // part1
tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**I'm adding two data sections to the table row**

```
TextView label_hello = new TextView(this);
         label_hello.setId(20);
         label_hello.setText("HELLO");
         label_hello.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);          // part2
         label_hello.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         tr_head.addView(label_hello);// add the column to the table row here

         TextView label_android = new TextView(this);    // part3
         label_android.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
         label_android.setText("ANDROID..!!"); // set the text for the header  
         label_android.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
         label_android.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
         tr_head.addView(label_android); // add the column to the table row here
```

**After adding the columns to the table row its time to add the table row the the main table layout that we fetched at the start**

```
tl.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,                    //part4
                 LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT));
```

**EDIT : YOU CAN DO THE FOLLOWING IN YOUR CODE**

```
 TextView[] textArray = new TextView[productsList.length()];
 TableRow[] tr_head = new TableRow[productsList.length()];

 for(int i=0; i<productsList.length();i++){
 JSONObject product = productsList.getJSONObject(i);
 JSONObject productData = product.getJSONObject("Product");
 String productDescription = productData.getString("description");

//Create the tablerows
tr_head[i] = new TableRow(this);
tr_head[i].setId(i+1);
tr_head[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
tr_head[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

 // Here create the TextView dynamically

 textArray[i] = new TextView(this);
         textArray[i].setId(i+111);
         textArray[i].setText(productDescription);
         textArray[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
         textArray[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         tr_head[i].addView(textArray[i]);
```

// Add each table row to table layout

```
tl.addView(tr_head[i], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

} // end of for loop
```

Creating the TextView and TableRow array are not necessary. You can just include `part1`, `part2`, `part3` (if you need more than 1 field) and `part4` inside your for loop.

Comment: @JuanPedroMartinez please comment in English, so that everyone can understand it.

Comment: He tries to say that you did a great job. However, it gives me an error, and I don't know how to solve it. :)

Comment: tr_head.addView(textArray[i]); tr_head hasn't the method addView

Comment: oops, please make it as `tr_head[i].addView(textArray[i]);`

Comment: Now this is solved, but when I run the app, it crashes. The log cat says nullPointerException

Comment: I think the problem is here: tr_head[i] = new TableRow(this); I can put "this" because the function is Runnable, and it gives error. so I put "getApplicationContext()" instead

Comment: then put the appropriate `context` instead of `this`. Is it working now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55187/discussion-between-aniruddha-and-julia).

Answer (score 1):

Look, i think you have to modify your xml to adding rows to your tableview:

First, the inflater:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
```

or in this way:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



 //Here you can set up the layoutparameters from your tableview and the rowview.
 //Maybe you don't have to modify nothing from the parameters of your tableview so
 //you can dismiss it.

 TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 //Here were we take the tablelayout from your xml
 TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tableOfProducts, null);

 //Like a told you before, maybe you don't need set the parameters of the tablelayout
 //so you can comment next line.
 tableLayout.setLayoutParams(this.tableParams);

 TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
 tableRow.setLayoutParams(this.tableParams);

 //Here you have to create and modify the new textview.
 TextView textView = new TextView(context);
 textView.setLayoutParams(this.rowParams);

 tableRow.addView(textView);

 tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

If you need more help, tell me, if it is helpful, rating me!!! ;) Un saludo Gallega! O como se dice en gallego: una aperta!

Comment: It gives me problems because my function is runnable, in the line: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); Do you guess why? Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: for LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), use yourActivityName.this instead of only "this".

Comment: Did Pankaj help you with your last question? If not, there are others solutions I think.

Comment: @Julia can you check my answer?

Comment: Hi Aniruddha, I'm trying it, but it doesn't work. The error is here: tr_head.addView(textArray[i]);

Comment: Sorry about my continuous questions, but I'm new at android :S

Comment: @Julia I have updated the answer, please check now and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

for this, you have to create one xml file for row, then you have to modify your layout.xml file like

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout orientation=vertical id="+id/rowHolder">
  </LinearLayout
</scrollview>
```

Then in for loop, inflate the row layout and add it runtime to rowHolder object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new myself to Android, and after years with Python/Gtk, I'm lost if I can't think in terms of Model/View/Presenter.

one useful approach I managed to apply, it puts me back into that optics, and even if it's not relative to a Table, I'm quite sure it can be extended to that (I guess [this page](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) would be a good start, for me too).

start by declaring the two objects in your fragment (or activity):

```
List<String> stringList;  // think of it as the model.
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;  // and this would be the presenter
```

define the model in the fragment constructor:

```
stringList = new ArrayList<>();
```

next, when the onCreateView of my fragment is invoked, I do this (edit correspondingly if you're using Activity, not Fragment):

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_taxonomy, container, false);
ListView mainListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.taxonomy_results);

// Create ArrayAdapter using the string list.  think of it as the presenter.
// see how it's being handled a model and a view.
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
        rootView.getContext(), R.layout.textrow, stringList);

// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

`textrow.xml` is an extra layout which is being reused every time I add an element to the `stringList` model.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

in the rest of the code, I only "talk" to `listAdapter`, and I only need its two `add` and `clear` methods, to add elements, or for clearing the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. First, for minimizing your code, create an XML file that initializes the `TableRow` and its attribute (`TextView` should be also included). Then, in your target XML file that is linked to the activity, you have to create only the `TableLayout`.

In the main, create LayoutInflater that will link the items to gather. Then, create as much as you can of the number of `TableRow`. In the end, each `TableRow` that has a unique variable should be linked using `addView()` to the `TableLayout` that you have created in the XML.

For more, see here. https://github.com/AreejTurky/Dynamic-TableRow-Generation